# How to force only allow swiping one slide at a time in swiperjs slider

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, swiper.js

Here is the URL of the website: https://manageprojectsdemo.com/test2/

I'm using swiperjs and would like to only allow the user to swipe one item at a time.

```
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    spaceBetween: 0,
    loop: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 4000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".left98",
      prevEl: ".right98",
    },
  });
  var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
    direction: "vertical",
    slidesPerView: 1,
    loop: false,
    speed: 1000,
    mousewheel: true,
    longSwipes: false,
    continuousVertical: false,
    scrollOverflowOptions: null,
    threshold: 1,
    shortSwipes: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
});
```